# Is Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll Redistributable?

Tags: c#, iis-7

We are accessing default port number using ServerManager class from IIS in customer machines. But the Console didn’t run some of the machines and show Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll is required. Is this assembly is Redistributable? Or Is there any other way to get the default Port number?
I am using below code to get the Port Number.

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            SiteCollection allsites = serverManager.Sites;
            foreach (Site site in allsites)
            {
                if (site.Name == "Default Web Site")
                {
                    BindingCollection allBindings = site.Bindings;
                    foreach (Binding bind in allBindings)
                    {
                        if (bind.Protocol == "http")
                        {
                            PortNo = bind.BindingInformation.ToString();
                            int portNoLenth = PortNo.Length; PortNo = PortNo.Substring(2, portNoLenth - 3); break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not redistrbutable, it should be installed in the machine with IIS. Even if you did, the likelihood is it will not work since it has dependencies on other libraries (native code DLLs) that need to exist and be registered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have create another console with this code and call the console if IIS is installed in Customer machine. It helps me to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but I believe that it is now redistributable as it appears as an assembly under extensions if you try to add a reference to it.

[image: Microsoft.Web.Administration reference]

Comment: The version you mentioned is for IISExpress and will not work for IIS.