# Should I reference assemblies from the WinSxS folder?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, winsxs, web-administration

I want to use the Microsft.Web.Administration.dll Assembly. On my Windows 7 the file is located only in the folder c:\windows\winsxs. Why is the assembly in this folder and is it reccomended to reference from there?

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather copy it somewhere locally and reference it from there if you really need it.

Comment: Only if it is explicitly redistributable. I don't think you can legally ship MS stuff otherwise.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248365/is-microsoft-web-administration-dll-redistributable